# Count number before search query is found

Tags: c#, string, pi

I am trying to determine how far I have to go in pi to find a user-input search query. I attempted to use various properties of `system.length`, but I was unable to get was I was wanting. I essentially want to be able to enter a set of numbers, and have the console return how many numbers into pi the query was found. The delimiter is `PiClass.CalculatePi` is just to make sure it does not run forever.

```
    Console.WriteLine("type string to search");

    string searchForThis = Console.ReadLine();

    var PiClass = new PiClass();
    double.TryParse(PiClass.CalculatePi(3), out double pi);

    string piString = pi.ToString();

    if (piString.Contains(searchForThis) == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Located");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please expend search");
    }

    Console.Read();
```

Comment: Why to you need to part Pi to `double` and then convert back to `string`? I think you want to use `string.IndexOf` function to get first index of matching substring.

Comment: What does `PiClass.CalculatePi` do? What is not working with your current code?

Comment: The tryparse is there for future changes, i am going to need to be able to use it mathmatically as a double, but i also need it in string form for this part.. I am tryign to ge to code to search for a string, and then tell me how many characters come before the searched string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
        Console.WriteLine("type string to search");
    string searchForThis = Console.ReadLine();
    var PiClass = new PiClass();
    double.TryParse(PiClass.CalculatePi(3), out double pi);
    string piString = pi.ToString();
    int location = piString.IndexOf(searchForThis);
    if (location >=0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Located  at index: " + location.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please expend search");
    }
    Console.Read();
```

Comment: testing piString.Contains is not really needed here, I think indexOf will return -1 if it does not find it, so you could just check if location>=0

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment you can use `string.IndexOf`:

```
string piString = pi.ToString();
int index = piString.IndexOf(searchForThis);

if (index != -1) {
    // There is a subsrting you are looking for.
}
```

And `index` will represent the number of characters that come before searched string.